# Using PoSH to get a value, strange results

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am using PoSH to query our Exchange server to return the largest mailbox by users.

My PoSH is:

```
$test = Get-MailboxDatabase MBX_* -Status | select Name,@{Name="NumberofUsers";Expression={(Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -Database $_.name).Count}} | Sort -Property NumberofUsers | Select Name -First 1
```

This works in console and returns:

```
Name
----
MBX_2
```

However when I run it like this in a script and return the value, it is like this:

```
$test = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status MBX_*| select Name,@{Name="NumberofUsers";Expression={(Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -Database $_.name).Count}} | Sort -Property NumberofUsers | Select Name -First 1
Write-Host "Using $test"

Using @<Name=MBX_2>
```

Why is it including the `@<Name=>` characters and how can I prevent it from doing that? I need to be able to grab just the returned value of "MBX_2" for the next part of my script and I am confused on how to go about this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting a single property of the object, but still passing an object. What you need to do is use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of the `Select-Object` cmdlet. Change your `Select` command to this:

```
| Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```

That should give you the results that you desire.